# Remove store code from Catalog Product Link Widget

Tags: store-view, widgets, product-links

I am adding product links to a CMS page using the "Catalog Product Link" widget feature. The inserted code looks like such:

{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_link" title="title" template="catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="product/99"}}

The links are display with the store code at the end, such as ?___store=default. How can I remove this extra part of the url from these particular links?

I've looked at catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml but I don't see where it says to display ?___store=default anywhere in the code.

NOTE: Under Add Store Code to Urls in admin, the option is selected to NO.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the `__store` parameter you can override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_Link` block and write the following code.

```
<?php

class Custom_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_Link
    extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_Link
{

    /**
     * Prepare url using passed id and return it
     * or return false if path was not found.
     *
     * @return string|false
     */
    public function getHref()
    {
        $href = parent::getHref();

        if($href) {
            if (strpos($this->_href, "___store") !== false) {
                preg_match_all('/(&*)?(___store=[a-z0-9_]*)+(&*)/i', $href, $matches);
                if($matches[2] != null) {
                    $replaceMatch = $matches[2];
                    if($matches[1] != null || $matches[3] != null) {
                        $replaceMatch = $matches[0];
                    }
                }
                $href = str_ireplace($replaceMatch, '', $href);
                $href = trim($href, '?');
            }
        }

        return $href;
    }
}
```

The `__store` parameter is used to switch between the store and load the appropriate content from the store view. I don't see a real need for that here as Magento also provides store view switcher that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the link code was generated from

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Widget/Link.php

I changed line 100 to

$this->_href = $this->_href;